# Facebook Open Graph returns false

Tags: facebook, graph, return-value

I am trying to access `http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}`. It usually returns all the **public** information about users, i. e. first and last name, gender and locale. However, on some very rare occasions, it simply returns false, there's not even an error. I have seen other questions on StackOverflow, and it's been said there that the access token may be wrong or the query format may be erroneous, but all I pass is the Facebook user id. Why is that?

Also, if it depends on the user's privacy settings, how can I enable/disable it for myself, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if the user opts out of the Facebook platform entirely.  Users can do this under Privacy Settings -> Ads, Apps, and Websites -> Turn Off All Apps.  Your developer account probably can't until you deleted any applications you have created, so I would try this with somebody elses account.

Comment: Thanks! And here the remaining characters to submit this comment.